# Agrupar elementos en HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero tener un `slider` que contenga x número de imágenes o diapositivas. Bien, si el `slider` contiene 3-4 elementos es cómodo de realizar, ¿pero y si contiene 40?

**¿Cómo podría agrupar los elementos imagen para hacerlo más sencillo?** El texto de las imágenes sería "1.jpg", "2.jpg", "x.jpg" para hacerlo más cómodo en la búsqueda y en el posible `for` o `while` que tengamos que programar. ¿Se podría programar en `Javascript` haciendo referencia al `id` de `img`?

Código:

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 1500); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides { display: none; }
  
#centrar
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="centrar">
 <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="5.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="6.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="7.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="8.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="9.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="10.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="11.jpg">
 <img class="mySlides" src="12.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Pues puedes hacer la cadena tú, la que vas a meter en el html, con js, entonces digamos en un `for` tener un la cadena `cadena += "<img class='mySlides' src='"+ i + ".jpg'">` algo así, según lo que entiendo, dime y te lo planteo como respuesta con un ejemplo mejor

Comment: Sí, tenía pensado hacerlo con Javascript, tener solo un <img src> en el <di> que englobe las imágenes y hacer referencia a él mediante DOM en Javascript. ¿Cómo lo ves?

Comment: Pues podrías intentarlo y mirar a ver que cosas no te dan y agregarlo a la pregunta, porque siento que hay algo que no puede cuadrar, pero no sabría hasta verlo, intenta hacerlo y sí te quedas estancado lo agregas y me comentas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear una función, que definiendo una serie de parámetros, te genere dinamicamente un carrusel. De esta manera podrías usarla para diferentes casos.

Se me ha ocurrido identificar el número de diapositivas que tiene el carrusel, la ruta de la imagen (una misma ruta y el mismo nombre de imagen con un número incremental para diferenciarlas), el **ID** del elemento al que deseamos insertar las imágenes y la extensión que tienen las imágenes. Podrías parametrizar más cosas pero con estas 4 tienes un buen punto de partida.

```js
window.onload = function() { 
  myIndex = 0; 
  generar_slider ('centrar', 20, 'gatitos', 'jpg', 'mySlides');
};

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  
  myIndex++;
  
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }    
  
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 1500); // Change image every 2 seconds
}

function generar_slider (id_slider, numero_diapositivas, ruta_imagen, extension_imagen, clase) {
  //Se captura el elemento que contendrá el carrusel mediante el "id_slider" pasado a la función
  let carrusel = document.getElementById(id_slider);

  //Se realiza un bucle que itera tantas veces como número de imágenes necesitemos.
  //El número se obtiene del parámetro de entrada "numero_diapositivas"
  for (var i= 1; i <= numero_diapositivas; i++) {
    //Se crea y almacena un elemento <img>
    let imagen = document.createElement("img");
    //Se le añade la ruta de la imagen que se visualizará.
    //La ruta se obtiene de la concatenación de los parámetros de entrada "ruta_imagen"
    //(la ruta comprende las carpetas si las hubiera más la imagen) con la extensión de la imagen y
    //separados por un punto.
    imagen.src = ruta_imagen + i + '.' + extension_imagen;
    //Se le añade a la imagen la clase pasada como parámetro de entrada (en nuestro caso "mySlides")
    imagen.classList.add(clase);
    //Se cuelga la imagen en el DOM, concretamente en el contenedor que contiene el carrusel.
    carrusel.appendChild(imagen);
  }
  
  //En esta parte ya se han cargado en el DOM todas las imágenes por lo que entonces llamamos
  //a la función "carousel()" para que las mueva.
  carousel();
}
```

```css
.mySlides { display: none; }
  
#centrar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-section" id="centrar">
 
</div>
```

**EDIT**

La manera en la que lo plantee en un principio daba lugar a que la función `carousel()` se llamara antes de que las imágenes se cargaran en el **DOM** por lo que tuve que modificar la función `generar_slider` para que en cada iteración del bucle inserte la imagen en vez de insertarlas todas de golpe al final de la función.

Comment: Se podría también pasar a la función un `array` con las rutas de las imágenes a insertar, así no tendrías ni que tener en cuenta el nombre, la extensión y el número de imágenes, tan solo recorrerlo e ir creando dinamicamente las imágenes.

Comment: En mi caso, todas las imágenes están el mismo directorio/carpeta: podrían llamarse "imagenX.jpg". ¿Entonces de qué forma sería para agrugarlas y no escribir tantas líneas de <img src> como elementos tenga el carrusel?

Comment: La función que he puesto resolvería ese problema. ¿Qué es lo que no comprendes de ella?

Comment: Integrar esa función en mi código trastocaría todo. No me gustaría cambiar la "estructura de mi código" (salvo reemplazar la línea <img src>)

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta para que la veas integrada con tu código y sin que el código que aportas quede apenas modificado.

Comment: Voy a echarla un vistazo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99703/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-phpmyguel).

Answer (score 1):

Se podría crear el elemento `<img>` dinámicamente usando la clase `Image()`:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {

  const img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLuNu.jpg?s=48&g=1";
  img.id = "i" + i;
  document.body.append(img);

}

const imagen3 = document.getElementById("i3");

console.log(imagen3)
```

la ventaja sería que por un lado la clase `Image()` tiene el evento `.onload()` y por otro, que si no haces el `.append()` sirve para precargar las imágenes.